# How to use observables in propagation

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to make an  authorization and faced the following task:

There is a service that gets the user from the frontend. I want to store this user in the service itself. To do this, I use the `checkUser()` function. Next, from component, I want to access this variable and when it changes in service, these changes were received by  the component. I thought that I can use  `Observable` (`getCurrentUser()` function in the service) for this. But the component does not come up with anything. Can you tell me what is wrong and how I can implement this? Thanks in advice.

#### Service:

```ts
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // public user: Account;
  public user: Account;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.checkUser();
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Auth: ', this.user);
    }, 2000);


  }

  checkUser() {
    return this.http
      .get<Account>(API_URL + '/get_user', { withCredentials: true })
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log(this.user);
      });

  }

  login(user) {
    this.http
      .post<Account>(API_URL + '/login', user, { withCredentials: true 
}).take(1)
      // .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('Resp: ', response);
        this.checkUser();
      });
  }


  getCurrentUser(): Observable<Account> {
    return Observable.of(this.user);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

}
```

#### Component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  // public user$: Observable<Account>;
  public user: Account;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.user);
    }, 2000);


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getCurrentUser().
      subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log('Navbar: ', user);
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working Plunkr?

Comment: I'd like to, but never used it and backend is written on Go.  Here's current github version: https://github.com/therox/trans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be worth to interest about `Subject`?

Service code:

```ts
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private user: Subject<Account> = new Subject();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.checkUser();
    }

    checkUser() {
        return this.http
            .get<Account>(API_URL + '/get_user', { withCredentials: true })
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(user => {
                this.user.next(user);
            });
    }

    login(user) {
        this.http
            .post<Account>(API_URL + '/login', user, { withCredentials: true })
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.checkUser();
            });
    }

    getCurrentUser(): Observable {
        return this.user.asObservable();
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

No need to change component.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's it.